# Win32 API prevent standby

Tags: c++, winapi, shutdown, standby

What is the Win32 api function that prevents the system from going into standby?

[Some programs](https://superuser.com/questions/132355/windows-will-not-go-into-standby) use it, which is pretty annoying in my opinion.

I know there's a couple of [WM_SYSCOMMAND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646360(VS.85).aspx) messages you can trap to prevent the screensaver from coming on..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SetThreadExecutionState.  There's no Get and it doesn't take a thread handle.  Done.

Comment: And to kill that, you'd probably need to intercept it using Microsoft Detours