# Is there a way in VB to readkey but if no key is pressed the code will carry on

Tags: vb.net

I want to have code that wants a key to be pressed within a certain time frame, if no key is pressed nothing will happen and the code will carry on as normal (console mode)

For snake game.

Comment: Hi RyanJA! Welcome to SO! Please make sure you read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If you can show what you've already tried, you're more likely to receive help!

Comment: For a game you need to capture key events and react to them as they are pressed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keypress?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: [VB.NET: How to know time for which system is idle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280799/vb-net-how-to-know-time-for-which-system-is-idle)